# How can I get Manipulator control elements to appear on one line?

Tags: manipulate, interface, interactive

By default `Manipulator` produced by `Manipulate` with `Appearance -> "Open"` option have two rows: on the first row the slider is placed, on the second other controls:

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], 
      Plot[Evaluate@D[Sin[x (1 + a x)], x], {x, 0, 6}]
     }, BaseStyle -> ImageSizeMultipliers -> 2/3], 
 {a, 0, 2, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

[image: screenshot]

How can I get all the controls placed on one row?

Comment: Don't know of an option to `Manipulator`. Perhaps place them individually? (E.g. `Row[{Slider[Dynamic[foo]], 
  InputField[Dynamic[foo], FieldSize -> Tiny], 
  Animator[Dynamic[foo], AnimationRunning -> False, 
   AppearanceElements -> {"StepLeftButton", "StepRightButton", 
     "PlayPauseButton", "FasterSlowerButtons", "DirectionButton"}]}, 
 Spacer[1]]`

Comment: there is no option build-in for this. You try @MichaelE2 method above, that would be the best solution. May be suggestion should be send to support@wolfram.com for this. I wanted to do this once and found no direct way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following suggestions in the comments, here is a way to achieve what I want:

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{
   Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}],
   Plot[Evaluate@D[Sin[x (1 + a x)], x], {x, 0, 6}]},
               BaseStyle -> ImageSizeMultipliers -> 2/3],
 {a, 0, 2,
  Grid[{{
         Slider[##, Appearance -> Tiny], 
         InputField[#, FieldSize -> Tiny], 
         Animator[##, AnimationRunning -> False, 
          AppearanceElements -> {"StepLeftButton", "StepRightButton", 
           "PlayPauseButton", "FasterSlowerButtons", "DirectionButton"}]
       }},
          Alignment -> {Center, Center}] &}]
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You probably want `Slider[##, Appearance -> Tiny]` -- `Manipulate` passes the domain as a second argument, `(0, 2}` in your example.

Comment: @Michael Thanks, I have corrected my answer. But it does not solve the problem with `InputField` positioning.

Comment: Do you mean vertical alignment?  Try `Grid[{{..}}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}] &`.  Also set `InputField[#, ImageSize -> {60, 15}]` to get a better match.  Cribbed from SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/MiscExpressions.tr (look for `"Manipulator04"`).

Comment: @Michael Thanks, I think the problem is solved (a bit strange that it was so hard, btw). If you wish you can post it as an answer and I'll accept it and delete mine. Or I just leave everything as is.

Comment: Oh, I have enough rep and not enough time, so let's leave it as it is.  Thanks, anyway! :)

Comment: Is there a way to make the controls for several, unrelated variables appear on the same line?

Comment: @Aron Yes, just include the controls in the `Grid[{{...}}]`.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look, if this will be better:

```
    Manipulate[
 Row[{Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], 
   Plot[Evaluate@D[Sin[x (1 + a x)], x], {x, 0, 6}]}, 
  BaseStyle -> ImageSizeMultipliers -> 2/3], {a, 0, 2, 
  Row[{Slider[#, ImageSize -> {200, 20}], 
     InputField[#, ImageSize -> {50, 17}], 
     Animator[#, AnimationRunning -> False, 
      AppearanceElements -> {"StepLeftButton", "StepRightButton", 
        "PlayPauseButton", "FasterSlowerButtons", 
        "DirectionButton"}]}, Spacer[1], 
    BaselinePosition -> Center] &}]
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately your code produces worse output in *Mathematica* 8.0.4 under Windows 7 x64 than the code in my answer.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov are your names different or what is the reason of `i` and `y` at the and? :)

Comment: @Kuba The names are of the same origin. The way they are written reflects the madness of the Russian Foreign Office inventing, re-inventing and re-re-inventing rules of how to write our names as well as a personal luck. I suggest you distinguish us by the family names.