# Make several separate Manipulate controls on a single line?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

How do I make several different `Manipulate` controls appear on a single line? I currently have both a `Slider` and an `Animator` controlling different variables and they appear one underneath the other. Is there a way to make them appear on the same line?

I've read [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37346/how-can-i-get-manipulator-control-elements-to-appear-on-one-line), but that deals with control elements of a single variable. How do I do the same for the different control elements of two or more variables?!

[image: Two variable controls appearing on different lines]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might use [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Row.html). For example:

```
Manipulate[{u, v}, Row[{Control[{u, 0, 6}], Control[{v, 10, 20}]}, Spacer[10]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Related https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFqi1mkuzJc

Comment: @belisarius: I lol'd...

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much!

Comment: @Aron: glad you find it useful. Take a look at the advanced manipulate section [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html#163301540), info on this kind of thing, and extensions.