# Order of display of AppearanceElements

Tags: plotting

I am using `Animate` and want the order of the controls to be `{"ProgressSlider", "ResetButton", "StepLeftButton", "StepRightButton"}`.

But what the controls are displayed in the following order `{"ProgressSlider", "StepLeftButton", "ResetButton", "StepRightButton"}`.

How do I get my "custom" order instead of the built-in order ?  Note that at the appropriate point I use `AppearanceElements->{"ProgressSlider", "ResetButton", "StepLeftButton", "StepRightButton"}`.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: You can use [this approach](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37506/5478). You have to use `Manipulate` but that should not make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a custom control with the desired appearance:

```
animF = Row[{Animator[##, AnimationRunning -> False, 
                AppearanceElements -> {"ProgressSlider", "ResetButton"}], 
             Animator[##, AnimationRunning -> False, 
               AppearanceElements -> {"StepLeftButton", "StepRightButton"}]}] &;
```

Examples:

```
{animF[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[x]}
```

[image]

```
 Manipulate[a, {{a, 1}, 1, 10, animF}]
```

[image]